# Material-UI custom theme palette property yielding 'undefined' error in Jest

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

In short, I'm using Jest, React Testing Library, and Material UI `createMuiTheme` and everything works except for the tests.  They break only when I add the custom theme from my compound theme from `createMuiTheme`.

I'm creating a custom theme for my MUI project as follows:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const theme = {
  palette: {
    extra: {
      activeButton: '#D4564E',
      black: '#000000',
      darkGrey: '#232323',
      rgbaInvisible: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      success: '#4CAF50',
      white: '#FFFFFF',
    },
  },
};

export default createMuiTheme(theme);
```

My component styles are defined in JSS like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    ctaCopy: {
      color: theme.extraColors.activeButton,
    },
  };
});
```

The component itself I don't think is important but it looks like this:

```
<Link className={classes.ctaCopy} href={ctaUrl}>
  {ctaCopy}
</Link>
```

This works.  The component displays properly **when rendered**, with the expected colors.  However, when I use this component in a Jest test, it fails, saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeButton' of undefined
```

**Update:**

I dug a little further and attempted a few other solutions, including using `MuiThemeProvider` and `ThemeProvider` (separately, of course).  In order to do this, I used `import` to pull in my custom theme, which is hosted in an external library.  As follows:

```
import { defaultTheme } from 'my-external-lib';
```

This, again, works on a rendered page.  I went so far as to `console.log` the `defaultTheme` and it prints correctly, again, in the rendered page.  However, in the tests, if I `console.log(defaultTheme)` the result is undefined!!

So perhaps the updated question nuance is, why can't I use `import` in this way with Jest/React Testing Library?

This may warrant a whole new question being posted.

More of what I've tried so far:

```
// This theme created as above
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { defaultTheme } from '@my-external-lib';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const setupComponent = ({
  ctaCopy,
  ctaUrl,
} = {}) => {
  render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
      <MyComponent
        ctaCopy={ctaCopy}
        ctaUrl={ctaUrl}
      />
    </ThemeProvider>,
  );
};

const testCtaCopy = 'test-cta-copy';
const testCtaUrl = 'https://www.test.com';

describe('My component', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    setupComponent({ ctaCopy: testCtaCopy, ctaUrl: testCtaUrl });

    expect(screen.getByText(testCtaCopy)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Why am I getting this error in *tests only*?

Comment: Are you using maybe these libraries?  "@testing-library/jest-dom", "@testing-library/react", "@testing-library/user-event". Is the render function from testing-library, or from react?
I have similar test environment and it works for me.

Comment: Hi, would like to see if there's any update on this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @theabrar and others who may find this SO question in the future, this was for a project at work and I no longer work there, so can't confirm or deny any fixes work in this environment.  :(  Sorry.  Also MUI has moved on from the version I was using, so that may also complicate matters (not sure the effect on themes over major versions).

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this today, the solution that fixed for me is this

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    ctaCopy: {
      color: theme.extraColors?.activeButton,
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm very new to JS, React, and Jest, but I was able to fix a similar problem where I got a similar error (related to the new MUI v5 update) so here's my best guess:

Perhaps you receive errors on test and not when running src, because:

1. the scope of your test and src code is different. The src code understands how theme's are being passed around and utilized in all your different src code files. Or:
2. Your test code is making assertions that the compiler doesn't care about.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'activeButton' of undefined`, Sound's like your theme isn't being picked up and used by makestyles() properly. (although it looks like you followed the docs perfectly fine & displayed your theme, so my guess is this is an issue on the JEST side or a minor bug with MUI)

What I did to fix a similar error was move my theme into the same file as my JSS, and refer to my theme directly in makeStyles(), rather than pass `theme` as a param.

So something like:

```
const themeAttr = {
  palette: {
    extra: {
      activeButton: '#D4564E',
      black: '#000000',
      darkGrey: '#232323',
      rgbaInvisible: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
      success: '#4CAF50',
      white: '#FFFFFF',
    },
  },
}; 

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeAttr);

const useStyles = makeStyles( => {
  return {
    ctaCopy: {
      color: theme.extraColors.activeButton,
    },
  };
});
```

I did not use `createMUITheme` in my project. I only used `createTheme()`. However this did fix the errors I was receiving during test, so I hope this helps!